# Double quoted values no longer escaping comma in CSV

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a csv file that has cells that have values with commas in it. I've already browsed a lot of threads on how to escape the comma to be displayed in a cell and not to be treated as data separator. All of the solutions I've found so far is about placing the value with comma in a double quote but it seems not working at all.

Here's the text file

[image]

While here's the result when opened in Excel

[image]

Am I doing it wrong? Or is there any good alternative to escape the comma on csv file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it. If you're encountering the same problem, all you have to do is to make sure there are no spaces before and after each comma separator.

In my case, I solved it by changing my text from this

```
col1, col2, col3
val1, "val2, with comma", val3
```

to this

```
col1,col2,col3
val1,"val2, with comma",val3
```